# Is the big-O complexity of these functions correct?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am learning about algorithm complexity, and I just want to verify my understanding is correct.

`1) T(n) = 2n + 1 = O(n)`

This is because we drop the constants 2 and 1, and we are left with n.  Therefore, we have O(n).

`2) T(n) = n * n - 100 = O(n^2)`

This is because we drop the constant -100, and are left with n * n, which is n^2.  Therefore, we have O(n^2)

Am I correct?

Comment: yes.............................

Comment: Thank you.  Appreciate the verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have those different levels determined by the "dominant" factor of your function, starting from the lowest complexity :

- `O(1)` if your function only contains constants
- `O(log(n))` if the dominant part is in log, ln...
- `O(n^p)` if the dominant part is polynomial and the highest power is p (e.g. `O(n^3) for T(n) = n*(3n^2 + 1) -3` )
- `O(p^n)` if the dominant part is a fixed number to n-th power (e.g. `O(3^n) for T(n) = 3 + n^99 + 2*3^n`)
- `O(n!)` if the dominant part is factorial
- and so on...